# Facing Invalid argument while accessing file on remote machine

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

I am facing the Error **Invalid argument** while reading an Excel file, placed on different system. The code works when i place the files on local machine

I tried using all the solutions mentioned like putting "/" in-place. I have also tried by giving real path (r'C:\blabla..').

```
def func_result():
    now = session['Dt']
    date_without_dash= now.split('-')
  date_to_check=date_without_dash[0]+date_without_dash[1]+date_without_dash[2]
    filename=(date_to_check+'.xlsx')
    loc = (r'\\172.17.5.126\g$')
    # full_path = loc+filename
    full_path = os.path.join(loc,filename)
    wb= xlrd.open_workbook(filename = full_path)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    total = [0]*27
    l=0
    for i in range(1,10):
        for j in range(3):
            k=l+j
            total[k]=sheet.cell_value(i,j)
            total[k]= int(total[k])
            # total.append(0)
        l=l+3
    rider = total[1:26:3]
    rider_sum = 0
    for x in rider:
        rider_sum+=x
    return render_template('result.html',ridership = rider_sum)
```

**Error**:

> **OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\172.17.5.126\\g$\\20190826.xlsx'**

Comment: to clarify: `xlrd.open_workbook` is throwing the error if you use '\\\\172.17.5.126\\g$\\20190826.xlsx' as `filename`? Does it work if you pass the filename e.g. to `os.path.exists` or `os.path.isfile`?

Comment: If i run in ATOM it shows as valid path, but when i deploy it, it shows Error 22 (as above).  both IDE and deployment are on same server.

Comment: hm to really sure what's going on here; what you could try is using `Path` from the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for path / filename creation and see if that works.

Comment: i checked with Path the same issue occurs after deployment and works fine on IDE.

Comment: @MrFuppes its solved. Actually the remote machine was not part of the domain. So now i use to connect/map drive each time it is accessing file and then un-map it. Thanks for your help.